# How to get rid of {{ }} matching error in Vim in HTML files?

Tags: angularjs, vim

I am writing some HTML + AngularJS code in Vim and  vim marks the second `}` as a matching error.

```
            This \
                  \
                   |    
<h1>Hello {{ name }} </h1>
```

I have already tried loading Vim with the default configuration, in case that some plugin is causing the problem, but the problem is still there.

Does this only happens to me or some of you have the same problem?

Some idea about how to solve this? Maybe disabling brace highlighting at all?

**EDIT:** The problem is my version of Vim (7.4.183), everything works fine in version 7.4.052.

**EDIT 2:** Oh no, this is so silly. The real problem was an unclosed tag. I guess it was just too much stress.

Comment: I've tried with my setup and with `vim -u NONE` and I see no error and can sucessfully use % to jump between braces. How is it showing the matching error for you?

Comment: @brettanomyces After opening the file with `vim -u NONE`, activate the syntax with `syntax on` and the the second closing brace appears with a red background (in the terminal).

Comment: What version of vim are you using? I have 7.4.274

Comment: Almost, Vim 7.4.183.

Comment: Interesting, it might be a problem with my version of Vim.

Comment: Hmm I tried on another machine with version 7.3 and I still don't get the error. Everything inside the <h1> tags is highlighted the same

Comment: I got it, is my version of Vim! I am now in Ubuntu with Vim 7.4.52 and the problem is gone. Thanks @brettanomyces, I found the problem thanks to you.

Comment: `:set ft=html` should have fixed it.

Comment: @Ben No, that doesn't fix the problem, thank you anyway.

Comment: When you have found the solution (or cause) to your own problem and no one have answered your question. You should answer it with your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my drama was because of this simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple app</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <style>
</head>
<body>
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
    <h1>Hello {{ name }} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem was not Vim, the problem was the `<style>` tag that I forgot to close. I recompiled vim 3 times before I realized of the real problem. I was just stressed and couldn't see my silly error.